# Translate image and copy incoming pixels with Pillow in Python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, affinetransform

I can use an Affine Transformation to translate an image in the normal way just fine. What I haven't been able to figure out is how to have the newly added pixels on the edges copy the value of the edge that was already there instead of defaulting to 0.

For example, the `Left` case below should have yellow pixels to the right of the block, and the `Up` case should have yellow below. Is there a way to accomplish this using an Affine transformation or some other method from Pillow?

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

image_size = (10, 10)


def translate(img, x, y):
    """Shift the image right x pixels and up y pixels."""
    return img.transform(img.size, Image.AFFINE, (1, 0, -x, 0, 1, y))

# generate a pattern
data = np.zeros(image_size)
for i, x in enumerate(data):
    for j, y in enumerate(x):
        if i >= image_size[0] / 2 and j >= image_size[1] / 2:
            data[i][j] = 255

im = Image.fromarray(data)
im = im.convert("L")

plt.subplot(321)
plt.title("Base")
plt.imshow(im)

plt.subplot(323)
plt.title("Left")
plt.imshow(translate(im, -1, 0))

plt.subplot(324)
plt.title("Right")
plt.imshow(translate(im, 1, 0))

plt.subplot(325)
plt.title("Up")
plt.imshow(translate(im, 0, 1))

plt.subplot(326)
plt.title("Down")
plt.imshow(translate(im, 0, -1))

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```